# Which Layout Manager to use for SOUTH and NORTH panels?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

In my Swing application I would like to have the following screen layout:

[image: screen layout]

Using `BorderLayout` here we have three panel placed: SOUTH, CENTER, NORTH.

Which layouts to choose for South and North panels? North has two components (labels): **left**-justified and **right**-justified. South has one component (button) in the **center**.

I would also like to have the entire screen re-sizable within reason.

It seems to me that I will have to use `GridLayout` for both with a lot of empty cells. Alternatively I could use a single `GridBagLayout` for the entire screen (but this approach will force me to have labels and button with proportional width).

Is there a better (and, may be, even easier) option?

Comment: A [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) with horizontal glues would probably be the easier choice.

Comment: @JBNizet I just realized that it will work for **North**, came back and you already suggested it.  Still not sure about about **South** though.

Comment: The south is a glue, followed by a button, followed by a glue.

Comment: @JBNizet - Wouldn't `FlowLayout.CENTER` be easier for South?  Again, why didn't I think of it *before* posting my question???

Comment: I guess so, yes. Test it.

Answer (score 2):

You can layer/nest `JPanel`s however you want, and give each its own unique Layout Manager.  This can sometimes lead to confusing behavior if you go too deep down the rabbit hole and layer things 4+ managers deep, but in this case, it makes things cleaner.

Add your two labels to a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`, specifying them into the `WEST` and `EAST` locations.

Add *that* `JPanel` into the `NORTH` location of your top-level `JPanel`, which also has a `BorderLayout`.  Your main panel goes into the `CENTER`.

Do a similar song and dance for the south - drop your button into a JPanel with whatever layout manager you'd like (`FlowLayout` might be nice, you won't have to add `Box` glue) and then drop that `JPanel` into the `SOUTH` location of your top-level panel.  Done! :)

Comment: Yes, I already selected `BorderLayout` for the overall screen. Your suggestion to use `BorderLayout` also for North is very interesting. Something I haven't considered at all.

Comment: As far as nesting goes, my Main Panel already goes 3 levels deep.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

- North - BorderLayout
- South - FlowLayout

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TestLayout.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                JButton northLeft = new JButton("Button");
                JButton northRight = new JButton("Button");
                JButton south = new JButton("Button");
                JTextArea text = new JTextArea(10, 40);

                JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                northPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0));
                JPanel northWest = new JPanel();
                northWest.add(northLeft);
                JPanel northEast = new JPanel();
                northEast.add(northRight);
                northPanel.add(northWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
                northPanel.add(northEast, BorderLayout.EAST);

                JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                southPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0));
                southPanel.add(south);

                JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                main.setBorder(new TitledBorder("BorderLayout"));
                main.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                main.add(text);
                main.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, main);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this so far seems to be the simplest configuration.